# What software can be used to create a restorable drive image?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, disk-image

Not sure what Linux software I would use for this. I'm looking for something like Acronis True Image for Windows, but for Linux. The rule is that we are keeping Windows out of the equation, I want to be able to rely solely on Ubuntu to handle the management and restoration of backup images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) is fairly popular though I've never used it. I would imagine you should be able to install it to its own partition and hack it into grub so it's there as a boot option (which I assume is what you're going for).

But most people just boot to it on CD or USB.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use the `dd` command.

To back up a drive partition (eg. /dev/sda1), run this command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=~/sda1_backup
```

and to restore:

```
sudo dd if=~/sda1_backup of=/dev/sda1
```

For more information on the `dd` command, see [man dd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/dd.1.html).

To reduce the space used by the backup images, you could use `gzip`, `bzip2` etc. to compress the images. If you do this, you will need to decompress the images before restoring.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use these:

- [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)
- [g4l](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/)
- [systemrescuecd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page)

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat newer tool is [FSArchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/), which is included on the [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) and supports restoring to partitions smaller than the original as long as there is enough space for all files.  It works with most filesystems that linux supports, can preserve both "basic" and "extended" attributes (e.g. for SELinux), can compress the archives with lzo, gzip, bzip2 or lzma, and can store the archives encrypted.