# How to revert to old version of Ubuntu? Like Windows "Restore" points?

Tags: backup, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there such a thing as a restore point in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8888/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-restore-point-in-ubuntu)

I'm new to linux (Ubuntu 12.04) and I'm finding that as I try to do new things, I end up breaking parts of my installation.  It would be very useful if there is an easy way to back things up so that I can revert to a previous working version of my environment.  What's the best (and simple) way to do this?

I'm thinking it must be something like a Windows Restore point, but some of my searches have found people specifically saying there's nothing like that (it is not how linux 'works').

Comment: You can't restore it unless you have backup. What is gone is gone. Use Backup next time.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't make automatically restore points so if you did not do a backup *before* upgrading there's no way to *rollback*

Answer (score 0):

Well one option would be to use the Backup services in the System portion of System Settings.

Open it up and turn on Automatic Backups. That way your computer can be backed up when you want it to. Not exactly restore point but it's better than nothing.