# restore, refresh, or reset your PC like Windows 8

Tags: backup, windows-8, restore, reset

In Windows 8 there are the options to [restore, refresh or reset your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc).

1. restore: "If you think an app or driver that you recently installed caused problems with your PC, you can restore it back to an earlier point in time"
2. refresh: "If your PC isn't performing as well as it once did, and you don't know why, you can refresh your PC without deleting any of your personal files or changing your settings."
3. reset: "If you want to recycle your PC, give it away, or start over with it, you can reset it completely."

**What would be the equivalent in Ubuntu or how is Ubuntu different so that it would not even be necessary.**

I think to 1. and 3. there are already answers:

1. [Is there such a thing as a restore point in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8888/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-restore-point-in-ubuntu)

3. clean Install

to 2. (refresh) I haven't found anything. Is this maybe one of the advantages of Ubuntu that it's not even necessary to perform any task like that?

Comment: I don't necessarily think that this is a duplicate. This question is asking for much greater detail in regards to resetting your OS that simply rolling back to a last know functioning configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Usually running the following command is sufficient:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

**Explanation:**

Almost all packages that are installed with `apt-get`, will have your user settings stored in your `/home/user` folder. And that previous command will not touch your home folder but will reconfigure all the installed packages you have in your system.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get autoclean; sudo apt-get autoremove` will remove unnecessary software from the system, although I only do this for neatness, I've never noticed any speed changes as a result.