# Ubuntu 20.4 update broke my Nvidia 460 driver config

Tags: 20.04

It was working perfectly before. (Previous updates had broken it, like every 3 months, but it could be fixed by making `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` work after "fighting" with removing old versions, etc.)

This time, `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` does not fix it leaving the computer with 1 monitor and minimum resolution.

Comment: It got even worse after reinstalling Ubuntu (I let the "update while installing" checked). Now a newly installed Ubuntu is broken too, despite the installer itself detecting the hardware ok and working in multiple monitors with the natural resolution.

Comment: Exact same problem here: was working completely fine until this morning, upon update/restart it's no longer working. reinstalling Ubuntu with original USB stick doesn't fix it (I had "get latest updates" option checked, I need to redo without this)

Comment: Ubuntu & nvidia drivers support: the number 1 pain point for me

Comment: Reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 with the bootable USB doesn't fix the problem. Even with the option "get latest updates" option unchecked it was still getting updates

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: See here https://askubuntu.com/q/1323913/243321

Comment: I'm raising a related question on how to restore kernels and nvidia drivers when those issues occur as it seems this is a never-ending battle: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324140/restore-specific-kernel-modules-nvidia-drivers

Comment: Can you boot into previous kernels?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324140/restore-specific-kernel-modules-nvidia-drivers/1325371#1325371