# All resolution options except 1024x768 gone after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: nvidia, updates, display, display-resolution

I got prompted an update (20.04.2 LTS from 20.04.1 LTS) this morning, installed it and rebooted. Now, the only resolution available on my 4K monitor is 1024x768.
I have a nvidia 3090 card, run the monitor via DisplayPort.

Running `xrandr` shows me the following:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

My current (activated) driver is `nvidia-driver-460 (proprietary, tested)`. I tried switching to the nouveau driver without luck, so reverted back. I also tried adding a new resolution using `xrandr` without luck.

I also noticed that running the command `nvidia-smi` no longer works:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Any advice or suggestions?

**EDIT:** Another Base update in "Software Updater" was available today, 24h later, that come with some nvidia updates. After a restart, this solved the issue and I'm able to change the resolution back to 4k.

Showing today's update in `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2021-03-17  11:16:25
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.171'
Upgrade: linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1, 5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1+1)
End-Date: 2021-03-17  11:16:37
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably got bit by the same kernel upgrade I was bit by this morning.

Check `/var/log/apt/history.log` and you'll probably see something of the form

```
Commandline: apt -y full-upgrade
Requested-By: spl (1000)
Install: linux-image-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51, automatic), linux-headers-5.8.0-45:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51, automatic), linux-headers-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51, automatic), linux-modules-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51, automatic), linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.8.0.44.49, 5.8.0.45.50), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.8.0-44.50, 5.8.0-45.51), linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge:amd64 (5.8.0-44.50, 5.8.0-45.51), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.8.0.44.49, 5.8.0.45.50), libglib2.0-dev-bin:amd64 (2.66.1-2ubuntu0.1, 2.66.1-2ubuntu0.2), libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.66.1-2ubuntu0.1, 2.66.1-2ubuntu0.2), libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (2.66.1-2ubuntu0.1, 2.66.1-2ubuntu0.2), libglib2.0-doc:amd64 (2.66.1-2ubuntu0.1, 2.66.1-2ubuntu0.2), libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.66.1-2ubuntu0.1, 2.66.1-2ubuntu0.2), linux-generic:amd64 (5.8.0.44.49, 5.8.0.45.50), libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.66.1-2ubuntu0.1, 2.66.1-2ubuntu0.2), libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.66.1-2ubuntu0.1, 2.66.1-2ubuntu0.2)
End-Date: 2021-03-16  05:52:21
```

I backed those changes out as follows:

```
/usr/bin/sudo apt remove linux-headers-5.8.0-45:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt remove linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt remove linux-headers-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt remove linux-modules-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt remove linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64

/usr/bin/sudo apt install linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt install linux-headers-5.8.0-43:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt install linux-headers-5.8.0-43-generic:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt install linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic:amd64
/usr/bin/sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-43-generic:amd64
```

which reverted me to the previous kernel.  I then sacrificed a goat, took a great big slug of coffee, crossed my fingers and rebooted.

All returned to whatever passes for normal.

Your mileage may vary.

Note: You'll get some scary warnings about deleting a running kernel.  Hence the sacrificial goat.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm afraid this solution seem a little big too risky for me, given that this is my work machine that I use daily. Any other hints?

Comment: Understood. It was on my work machine, too. Other postings elsewhere have recommended installing `timeshift` so that you can roll back updates gracefully. I've installed but haven't tested yet. I'll try installing it on one of my sacrificial machines and test a rollback there. That would be certainly much easier than mucking with a running kernel!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm a similar issue. My computer reverted to 640x480, I was able to get this to 1024x768 but updating Grub.

It seems to be the "failed to get the size of gamma output" that is the issue.

I have tried to use CVT and xrandr to manually add a new resolution but this just results in the "failed to get gamma" output again.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer. See [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19074/when-should-i-answer-and-when-should-i-comment) for more infos

Answer (score 0):

Another Base update in "Software Updater" was available today, 24h later, that come with some nvidia updates. After a restart, this solved the issue and I'm able to change the resolution back to 4k.

Showing today's update in `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2021-03-17  11:16:25
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.171'
Upgrade: linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1, 5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1+1)
End-Date: 2021-03-17  11:16:37
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for me [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567684/suddenly-my-resolution-of-screen-changed-and-i-cant-reset-it)

Running the following commands in Terminal fixed this for me this morning

sudo apt install nvidia-settings

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

sudo reboot