# 20.04 LTS won’t boot after 03/16/21 update

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04, updates

I’m using a laptop with windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS partitions, and an Nvidia graphics card. The Ubuntu partition worked fine last night and booted normally this morning, but since installing today’s (03/16/21) update, the gnu grub menu works but Ubuntu won’t boot (black screen). I tried following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) but I can’t enter the TTY (I tried ctrl-alt-f3 as well), and editing the grub as they instructed didn’t work.

I then tried using a live disk with the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) under “Update Failure,” and was able to install updates and follow the instructions in the first link (using Nvidia 460 instead of 430), but now not only does Ubuntu not boot, even gnu grub doesn’t work (also shows a black screen, but booting directly to windows works fine).

I don’t have a much data on the partition, so if nothing else works, I’d rather wipe it and start fresh than try data recovery, but I’d still like to fix this if it’s possible. I’m not super familiar with Linux or computers in general so please give detailed instructions.

Comment: There is no "*today’s (03/16/21) update*." Due to *phased upgrades*, folks get gets different upgrades that even out over the course of a week or so. This sensibly protects from a single bad upgrade destroying everybody's systems on the same day. However, it means that we have no idea what upgrades you had.

Comment: There are several recent questions concerning a new kernel in 20.04 breaking desktop login. Try booting to the last kernel.

Comment: See here https://askubuntu.com/q/1323913/243321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at the similar posts and the suggestions didn’t work, and even the new update that fixed this for most people didn’t seem to work, but the new update + turning off secure boot did. Probably obvious to most people but hopefully this helps someone else having similar issues.