# How do we find out if the partition table recovered with testdisk is OK?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, data-loss, testdisk

We have a hard drive with damaged partitions. In deeper search testdisk found it but wanted to deletd all of the partition (and showed structure `OK` below):

[image]

We tried this one but then it showed the structure is `BAD` (below):

[image]

Another way which we thought was good is choosing all the other partition as delete, except to the last one, and to choose the important partition (the second one) as `L` and also `*`-bootable or `P(rimary)`:

[image]

We now need to know if that is OK so that we can apply the changes. There is more information if needed in [our post on the forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12012853#post12012853).

It is very important to recover all of our work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we do not know what incident damaged your drive, and we also do not know anything on the previous proper partition structure we unfortunately can not give you a reliable answer to your question.

However in case these lost data are really important, and we have no backups, we strongly recommend to run all the restoring commands on an image of the drive only. Alternatively it would also be a good idea to create an [image of the whole drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11067/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-to-an-image-that-i-can-open-later) to be able to restore to the previous state in case we further mess up the partition table. We can do so with

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=<path>/backup.img
```

Replace `<path>` with the location of your backup medium (e.g. an external drive).

Running [testdisk on an image](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) will save you a lot of headaches if something goes wrong, and it will also allow you to try out what you believe is right without any risk of further data loss. Run testdisk on the image as follows:

```
sudo testdisk <path>/backup.img
```

Comment: how can i make testdisk to scan the img file (we have a guide to gddrescue). but after creating the file, what should i do? i just dont get it.and                                                          what happend was making change in the partitino, but it took long and he shut the pc down.                                              are you sure i can't know if this structure is good or not?

Comment: thanks! but one thing i still dont know. how i'm recovering my data with the command (i know how ro run it). after i run it, what next? where will our data will be so we'll be able to copy/backup it?         thanks again you're helping us a lot!

Comment: testdisk will restore the partition table in the **image** file. Mount it and see if everything is o.k. - how to do this see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-disk-device-image

Comment: thanks! and one more question-can i do it easier with programes like "gmount" or "furius ISO mount"?                               you're making our day! (i'm trying to learn those phrases (: )

Comment: afaik are these tools for mounting CD-isos only. Here it's much different as we have an image holding several partitions, that's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

well i saw this three commands:

`testdisk image.dd` to create a raw disk image

`testdisk image.E01` to recover files from an Encase EWF image

`testdisk 'image.???`' if the Encase image is split into several files.

which command should i run and how? and what does it do?
we really need to know so very very very thanks!