# Ubuntu MATE pi - creating backup image

Tags: backup

I wanted to back my current state as an image but Im running into a problem: it seems that my microSD contains two partition: pi_root and pi_boot. How do I create an  exact image of my microSD card with two parititons using dd?

Comment: I'm not listing this as an answer as you requested `dd` but I'd encourage a look at Clonezilla (http://clonezilla.org)

Comment: I would also recommend **Clonezilla**. It is much safer and also faster than `dd`, See this description, https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248; Notice that it works with any kind of mass storage device: memory card, USB pendrive, SSD, HDD. I suggest that you create an image of the whole drive with the bootloader and all the partitions (a compressed image, which is a directory with a number of files). -- When you restore from the image, you need a target drive of at least the same size as the source drive (not one byte smaller). The same is true for `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dd`.

First you have to find the device name of the memory card, as this *may* depend on the card reader used. Run `sudo lsblk` The output will be something like this:

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.3G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0    56M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  29.2G  0 part /
```

In this case, `mmcblk0` is the only device, as it is done on a Pi. `mmcblk0` is typically the name used with memory card readers, but USB card readers may also show up as `sdb` and so on.

To make a complete backup of the whole card, issue the command `sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=filename.img`. If the device of the card is not mmcblk0, replace as per output of `lsblk` output.

This will read all of the memory card into the file `filename.img`. This should generally not be done from the Pi - as reading a live filesystem may lead to inconsistent results. Power off your Pi, and put the card into a different computer. Do not mount it.

To write the backup back to a card, reverse the input and outputs, i.e. `sudo if=filename.img of=/dev/mmcblk0`.

**Please be very careful, and read dd commands three times before you execute it. If you mix up input and output for instance, you risk destroying all your data!**

If you want to compress the image for storage, run for instance `bzip2 filename.img`. This will reduce the file size significantly, especially if you have a lot of free space. To decompress the image, for restoring, run `bunzip2 filename.img.gz`.

Comment: Args, didn't see you posted already an answer while i was writing on my one :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only used sudo fdisk -l and it only showed the partitions, not hte whole disk so I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `dd` you can do it like described below. Just a word of warning beforehand, there are simpler to use tools like [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) which are less error prone and probably far more performant as using `dd`.

First make sure you know the drive letters for your SD card (I assume here it is `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` containing your partitions). You can simply pull a full image of this drive by not addressing the single partitions instead using the drive itself (i.e. `/dev/sdb`). To fetch the full contents of that drive in an image do:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/myimage.img
```

to reverse it:

```
sudo dd if=~/myimage.img of=/dev/sdb
```

You may ask how you can get the proper drive letters to use, this you can by using `lsblk` which will produce an output similar to this:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 103,2G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     1G  0 part /media/<username>/pi_boot
└─sdb2   8:18   0    15G  0 part /media/<username>/pi_root
```