# Migrating OS drive and fresh installation

Tags: system-installation, windows, format, migration

I used Linux a while ago, but unfortunately I had to go back to Windows because of the need to use some proprietary software. However, since my laptop has 4GB ram, a 320GB HDD and a 32GB SSD, I am planning to use the HDD only for windows and the 32GB SSD for linux only (this space is enough for me to use).

My question is this: Currently Windows 10 is installed on the SSD and the HDD is with backup files, so what I would like to do is clone the system that is on the SSD to the HDD, which is practically empty, format the SSD and install linux on it.
I would like to do this cloning because all the programs I need from windows are already installed correctly and it would take a lot of work to have to reinstall everything.

Has anyone ever performed a procedure like this? What program can I use to do this cloning?

Is it necessary with 4GB of ram to put a swap on the SSD?

Comment: If you can allow the whole partition table on the target drive (the HDD), you can clone the whole SSD drive, provided that the **sector sizes** of the two drives are the same. You can check that with `sudo parted -ls`. I suggest that you use Clonezilla for that purpose. See this link, [Fastest way to copy HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248?s=2|45.5809#958248)

Comment: Then after I copy the OS for another drive I can just boot with an Linux iso, clean the old windows installation and proceed with the linux installation?

Comment: A lot of UltraBooks had 32GB SSD just for boot cache. And only the amount of RAM was used for the cache. Users kept Windows cache and still were able to install Ubuntu / (root) in remaining space and /home or /mnt/data on HDD. Are you sure all of Windows is in SSD? If 32GB that is about the absolute minimum for Windows. Be sure to have good backups and do not reboot with duplicate UUIDs. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred I'm using a 32bit version of windows 10 and still have 5GB of free space with all programs that I use in windows installed. So after I move the windows installation, I clean the ssd and install linux and do a boot-repair?

Comment: +1 to @oldfred's comment. I agree, that you should **take good backups of everything important before starting on this adventure**. -- You should check that Windows works from the HDD (with the SSD unplugged) before you start writing to the SSD.

Comment: It is my understanding that NTFS partitions like 30% free. At 10% free there is so little room that your defrag takes forever. But maybe with SSD defrag is not required as often.  Linux also wants some free space and even hides 5% to prevent crash, if user is monitoring space. Boot-Repair is only required if you have boot issues. And then you run report to see configuration. I typically run report to document configuration anytime system is changed a lot.