# How can I copy my sd card [multiple and different partition] without dd

Tags: tar

I copy to my sd card a lot. It's an 8gb card and has 3 partitions. I can copy with dd but its take so long about ten minutes. It's mini OS

```
 fat32 100mb sdb1 --> boot.scr, foo1, foo2
 ext4 7.2gb sdb2 --> file system general linux path etc,usr, root vb
 ext4 100~  sdb3 --> my scrips
```

How can I have mbr files, and I can create a partition. And can I mount  3 partitions somewhere (sdb1 -> sd1 look like).

How can I copy since I have a lot of symbolic links? I tried tar but it's not working for me or I can't. Can I include some permissions that are different in this so I can copy with tar?

Comment: You can clone faster and safer with **Clonezilla**. See this link, [Fastest way to copy HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248?s=3|18.4406#958248).