# how can I quickly clone a boot disk?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, cloning, ddrescue

I have a boot disk (running ubuntu) that is all set up with nginx, php, motion, and some other server stuff, on a 16GB disk drive, using the entire disk.

I have several computers to deploy this disk set up to, so I am making a disk image. I am wondering, if there is an expedient means of creating disk images from physical drives?

is there a means of cloning only what i need, so that the process is faster?

Comment: I suggest that you use Clonezilla for this task (to create an image and to make cloned copies from the image). See this link, [I would use Clonezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to copy HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd)