# Clone a whole drive via live session

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to move to Ubuntu for gaming also which means installing it on my gaming rig. In case things don't work out I want to be able to write a cloned image from an external HDD back to the SSD to start where I left. Is there a software for this?

Comment: Gnome-Disks I've used for cloning whole drives, and writing it back, (will take long time though,a  few or if it's a really big drive, many - hours).

Comment: I suggest that you download a [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) iso file, create a USB boot drive and use it to clone directly or create a compressed image. See [this AskUbuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248) for more details.

Comment: My SSD is 1TB. How long will it take?

Comment: Clonezilla will only copy used blocks, so it depends on the how much of that 1 TB that is really used by files, and it depends on the speed of the computer hardware (including the drives). If the computer is not too old, maybe 4 GB real data per minute to create the image (and maybe extra time for checking that the image is restoreable: 7 GB per minute, only if you wish to check).