# I copied my hdd to ssd with ddrescue it worked earlier but didn't work this time why?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, dd

I generally use this command `sudo ddrescue /dev/sda /dev/sdb --force` to clone my hdd ubuntu to ssd and the ssd would boot and work like a charm but .. this time the new ssd drive is not booting. does have to do with the file system in target ssd doesn't ddrescue or dd do a complete clone including file system and all.What can I do to clone my harddrive to ssd make that ssd a fully independent bootable disk;

Comment: Better to just do a new install & restore data from your normal backup. Helps to prove your backup is complete, also. You cannot reboot with both drives connected as you cannot have duplicate UUID or GUIDs. If cloning from booted install, you may not be copying everything anyway in sync as system is running. Clone should only be done from another system.

Comment: The target drive must be at least as big (not one single byte smaller) as the source drive, and the physical sector sizes should be the same for a clone to work correctly. You can find the sector size with for example `sudo fdisk -lu`. If a GUID partition table, GPT, you must also fix the backup partition table. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248) for more details. - `ddrescue` is a reliable tool and is not causing problems. It might still be a good idea to make a fresh installation and get rid of old cruft.