# What do I do in the Grub menu to get Ubuntu working

Tags: grub2, ssd

I have cloned a 500GB SSD for my dual boot Windows and Ubuntu system. I can boot into Windows 10 OK but Ubuntu (latest version - 22,04) just shows the Grub menu.

What do I do to get Ubuntu running?  Does Grub need fixing?

On my old HDD I added Linux to the original Windows system and it works OK

Comment: The following link may help you: [Fastest way to copy HDD - I would use Clonezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248). - You can clone in different ways and get a working cloned copy. What you should look at here are the *other conditions*: target size vs source size, partition table (extra caution if GPT), physical sector size, and possible bad sectors, that may cause problems in the cloning process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to sudodus who suggested Clonezilla.  I have used it and now my Linux boots first time.

The Clonezilla live disk is not the easiest to use but it is much better than the Acronis software supplied with the SSD and seems to know Linux well by installing GRUB and initrd files.  So I would suggested it to anyone who wants to clone a dual boot system Windows & Ubuntu system.

Comment: If you've found a solution for your problem, make sure to click the checkmark under the votes so everyone can see the question is solved. :)