# DD question copying 2 select partions to target

Tags: dd, cloning

Using ubuntu for few weeks now and its excellent.

Really like the dd copy tool but i would like some advice on using it.

I copied all my installers to a partitioned ssd i now need to reverse but each one is 2 parts an efi 200mb and then the installer 16GB.

obviously i can select partition 1 ( example sdc1 ) but it copies the 200mb part to the usb i am creating then stops. if i select the whole ssd obviously that is not good either.

is there a way to copy sdc1 and sdc2 to target

obviously depending on ssd i could need

sdc3 and scd4

i can do it with my copy tools on windows but like i say this is fast becoming my main tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copying 500 Gig from one portable to another using dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422740/copying-500-gig-from-one-portable-to-another-using-dd)

Comment: Best not to use dd unless copying entire drive, same size drive to same size drive. Gpt drives have GUID in primary partition table, backup partition table & partition. Copying one partition then also requires repair of gpt partition table. And if not copy to same size drive the backup partition table at end of drive is not at end of drive. Better, if Ubuntu, to just reinstall & restore from backup.