# How to backup a Ubuntu USB installation as a disk image?

Tags: backup, disk-image

I have Ubuntu installed in an USB drive. It is not a live or persistent live install. It is a regular, full install.

Is there any way to backup the USB drive to a .img or .iso file, which I can later use to restore a bootable version of Ubuntu to this USB drive or another USB drive?

Comment: I suggest that you use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) because it is efficient and safe. A Clonezilla image is a directory with a set of files, and the big files are compressed. Clonezilla is smart enough to copy only used blocks (in file systems known by its tool Partclone). See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248) where I explain more about Clonezilla.

Comment: The gnome-disks app has "Create Disk Image" as one of the menu options. This will create a .img file the size of the whole USB drive. You can use the same app to restore from a .img file to another USB drive of the same or bigger size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that this is a simplistic method, that will create large files already for "small" devices.*

**Backup:**

1. use e.g. `lsblk -ape7` to find out which `/dev/...` you have the USB drive positioned at
   *(e.g `/dev/sdc` to have a true dev to show below)*.
2. make sure the drive is NOT mounted
3. Open a terminal, type
   `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc bs=128k | gzip --best >/place/to/store/backup.img.gz`
4. hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and fill in the (root) password

**Restore:**
The example `/dev/sdc` needs to be same-size USB drive, or larger than the backup source.

***Also:** Make sure `/dev/sdc` is the CORRECT device,

all earlier content will be lost and will NOT be recoverable.*

Enter `gzip -c /place/to/store/backup.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc bs=128k`
in a terminal (at the bash prompt) and provide the requested input (root password).

Additional options to `dd` *(notrunc, noerror)* and `gzip` might be in place.

**Options:**
The image file produced by dd, when **uncompressed** (and at least of some common content types), may be mounted as a loop device:
`lodev=$(losetup -f)` - will create a device, if possible, and keep the name in $lodev
`sudo losetup $lodev imagefile` - will attempt to use the imagefile, create a 'removable' disk and mount the partitions in it.
`sudo losetup -d $lodev` -  will dismount the image, and deconstruct the loop device.

Comment: Note that this is a simplistic method, that will create large files already for "small" devices.

Comment: I am not very familiar with dd, can we add the progress indicator as described [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/dd-progress-indicator) ? If the progress indicator feature is compatible with this, can you please edit the answer to add that?

Comment: Should there be a space between `>` and `/place/to/store/backup.img.gz` ?

Comment: it should work as is.

Comment: Progress; Try just appending `status=progress` to the dd commands, it seems to work based on a simple check.