# What full partition/disk imaging solutions produce mountable images?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, disk-image

I want to make full disk images of different computers that I could later restore if something goes wrong. Also, being able to mount the image/access the backed up files would be really useful.

What are my options?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What software can be used to create a restorable drive image?](http://askubuntu.com/q/7576/6969).

Comment: I was hoping to find out if there was something that produced mountable images for me

Comment: Do you just want the iso format, or do you primarily want to back up to physical cd,s/dvd,s?

Comment: I would be saving to an external usb hard disk. I said "image" because I want to save the exact state of the system, so I could do a complete restore.

Answer (score 4):

To make the image you will probably want to use [Partimage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page)

So that the image is consistent, you will want to make sure the disk is offline when you make the image.

I have transformed Partimage images into virtual drives for VirtualBox.  It appears that you can also [Mount a partimage file as a loopback device](http://home.prea.net/node/107), but I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: The only downside I see is this limitation, which might not bother you too much: "Single files or directories cannot be restored. Although the backup could be restored to an temporary/alternate partition and single files or directories could be recovered from the alternate partition."

Comment: There are some ways to get at the contents of the image without restoring it to a physical drive.  I've updated the answer with what I know.

Answer (score 1):

Bacula is a free-as-in-speech linux backup program that allows bare metal and single file recovery. Also in its favour is it doesn't require an offline system to get a full system backup. It's a bit of a pain to set up, but the end result should be pretty sweet. The backup format is open source but Bacula specific. You need Bacula to access your backup.

http://www.bacula.org/en/